Are there any alternatives to .env files that make it possible to modify configuration in production?
I'm creating a new app using Vite. The app needs a baseURL to communicate with an external API.
One could use .env files for local dev and environment variables for production ( https://vite.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables-and-modes ), so I could pass in the baseURL in my CI/CD pipeline.
But since there are several app deployments on different systems I would have to create one build per system with the correct baseURL environment variable.
It would be better to be able to modify this baseURL configuration somewhere in production.
Are there any solutions to this?
I thought about passing in the baseURL as a URL parameter but my app got routing, things get tricky when I have to take care of passing the baseURL parameter to the next route..

This is precisely what .env files are for. That's where you put the data that should differ between environments.

@Barmar this is true but then I would have to create an individual build for each deployment / different machine?

I think environment files are usually managed separately from the application build, specifically to avoid this problem. They often contain secrets like application keys that shouldn't be stored in version control systems.

yes, of course. But if there are 3 systems that require different baseURL parameters you would have to create 3 different builds, right? Instead of deploying the app 3 times and just changing the baseURL in the configuration

Why? There's one build, and 3 config files outside of the build.

AFAIK that doesn't work for Vite. .env files and environment variables are populated during build time. Vite does not read any files during runtime
